# Multiple remote users of ROS master: nickname lookup failure

Tags: ros, multiple, master, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am setting up a ROS master that I want students to be able to access, without giving
them administrator privileges on that machine.
For this example a student laptop has the name vaio4 and has gotten an IP address through the campus wireless network DHCP.
The students are able to remotely say

```
rostopic list
```

but when they try

```
rosnode ping gazebo
```

the master machine prints out an error message about not being able to reach machine vaio4. If I put vaio4 with its current IP address in the /etc/hosts file on the ROS master, everything works.
It does not seem that saying

```
ROS_IP=xxx
or
ROS_HOSTNAME=xxx
```

on the ROS Master machine makes sense since it is talking to many laptops simultaneously, so which IP address should it use?
The laptop knows who it is and can reach the master.
It seems that the master should always use numeric IP addresses and not attempt to use machine names or nicknames.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59815/multiple-remote-users-of-ros-master:-nickname-lookup-failure/) by [cga](https://answers.ros.org/users/3998/cga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME on the laptop.  The problem is that the laptop is advertizing itself as vaio4 but the master cannot reach it by that name. See the [ROS Network Setup Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running avahi-daemon instead of static IP bindings in the hostfile.

If you're running on Ubuntu, avahi will be running by default, allowing you to reach the machine with the vaio4.local address.

Disregard ROS_IP and set ROS_HOSTNAME to $(hostname).local on each machine.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2